# view.frame.origin.y move to initial position when i'm start typing text Swift

Tags: swift

I set Keyboard listener with NotificationCenter and want to change view.frame.origin.y when focus field. But when I start typing my view.frame.origin.y move to initial position.

Register keyboard function

```
private func registerKeyboardAppearenceObserver() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}


@objc private func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

        if (self.view.frame.origin.y == 0) {
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height / 3
        }
    }
}

@objc private func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
        self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
}
```

[Initial app screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDgHN.png)

[Screen when any field focuses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLLfu.png)

[Screen when start typing in any field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMmP8.png)

Comment: Is there any other code which affects `self.view.frame`?

Comment: No, only in this listener

Comment: I don't think its the best idea to change the parent view's frame. Perhaps put your content in a container view that initially has the same frame as the parent view and update that container's frame

Comment: @JasonSilver thank you very much, it solved my problem

Comment: Great I'll add it as an answer if it solved it please accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think its the best idea to change the parent view's frame. Perhaps put your content in a container view that initially has the same frame as the parent view and update that container's frame